# Pass value on js button click to ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Is it possible to pass values from a js file to an ejs/html file on a button click? I am working with a Node.js program, and I am able to pass values from the app.js file to the ejs files like this:

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  res.render('home', {
    title: 'Home Page', 
  message: "Test message"})
});
```

I have a separate js file (planner.js), that is responsible for a subpages functions. On a button click, I want to send some variables generated in planner.js to the home ejs file. Right now, the planner.js file has a "on button click" location.href link that redirects to the home page, but I can not figure out how to pass the variable data on the button click as well.

This is what the planner.js button click looks like currently:

```
doneButton.on("click", function(){
        location.href = '/home';
});
```

Comment: I think your question is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616719/pass-a-variable-from-javascript-to-ejs

Comment: You could redirect to `/home?done=1` and then do `if (req.params.done) res.render('home', { title: 'Home Page', message: 'Done Message' })`